# Taxon queries in Spree API

Tags: spree, ransack

I'm trying to run searches using ransack queries, but I'm getting invalid search term results on the following `/api/v1/products?q[classifications_taxon_id_eq]=3`. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I deliberately set ransack to not ignore invalid terms, just to try to figure out what's going on.

The error I get is something like:

```
Invalid search term classifications_taxon_id_eq
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to whitelist classifications in the product model:

After that in the classification model, you need to whitelist the taxon attribute.

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb#L117

Comment: Geez, you'd think searching by product type would be enabled in the API by default.  Thanks!